# Not able to upload images to Django with form: 404 POST / not found

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls, django-staticfiles

I was trying to create a webpage where users can upload their images and store them in Django but for some reason am not able to upload it.

[image: This is what I get when I hit the upload button]

I [followed](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-uploading-images-in-django/) [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5YkEFLXcRg) [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaH8edyErQE).

This is the html code

```
 <form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Upload</button>
            </form>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"), )
```

models.py under the app Lightings

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MovieImage(models.Model):
    image_upload=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to="userimages/")
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class MovieImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=MovieImage
        fields=('image_upload',)
        labels={
            'image_upload':'',
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import MovieImageForm
from .models import *
# Create your views here.
def startlighting(request):
    return render(request,'Lightings.html')

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=MovieImageForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request,"Lightings.html")
    else: 
        form=MovieImageForm()
    return render(request,'Lightings.html',{'form':form})
```

urls.py at project level

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from homepage.views import start
from About.views import aboutstart
from Lightings.views import startlighting
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from Lightings.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("home",start),
    path("About",aboutstart),
    path("Lightings",startlighting),
    path("Lightings",index)
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending your request to the wrong url. You should go to **http://127.0.0.1/8000/Lightings** url. You have registered two function based views under this url.

Comment: Do you mean I've to change this from return render(request,"Lightings.html") to             return render(request,"http://127.0.0.1/8000/Lightings") But I get a invalid OS error and invalid argument error    \template\\http:\\127.0.0.1\\8000\\Lightings'

Comment: No, I mean, on your web browser, go to that url, you're on 127.0.0.1:8000 url now

Comment: Thanks now I can upload the  images but am kinda new to Django so do you know how to access the uploaded image so I can use it in my python program

Comment: What do you mean by accessing the uploaded image? Where and how do you wanna access it?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to hit the wrong url.
In urls.py, instead of

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("Lightings",index)
]
```

change it to

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("",index)
]
```